# Target single blog post template in functions.php for WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to target the single blog post template in the WordPress file `functions.php`.

I have the following code:

```
if( is_page_template( 'single.php' ) ){

} else {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```

Some reason this does not target the single blog post template. I know that this code works because it works when I put another template in there instead of `single.php`.

Why won't `single.php` get targeted in this?

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution

all i had to do was change `is_page_template` to `is_single`